# all data can show but "sEcho" value empty

Tags: php

```
 if (postVar('sSearch') !="" ) {
    $sWhere = " WHERE Line LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' OR ".
              "Model LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' OR ".
              "NIK LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' ";
    }
 $sQuery = "SELECT  Line, Model, NIK FROM   inspection_report ".$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
 $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );

 $sQuery = "SELECT  Line, Model, NIK FROM   inspection_report ".$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
 $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );

        $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
        $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to My$
        $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
        $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

        $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(Line) FROM   inspection_report";

        $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to MySQL an$
        $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
        $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

        $sOutput = '{';
        $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.$sEcho.',';
```

i've been use that code but why the result is empty? `{"sEcho": ,`

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? Nowhere in the code you posted $sEcho is set to anything, so it'll obviously be empty.

Comment: it make me confuse bcoz at firebugs (XHR): at params show sEcho :1 but at response sEcho: ,

Comment: I don't understand why you deleted your original question. As I said there, I think the problem is with the `postVar` method. You should show its code.

Comment: @felix Kling: sorry i have a mistake..i want to click edit but i click delete..and after i want to undelete some trouble happen at my PC..so i'm turn on my PC again and back to SO but the question have been missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sOutput = '{';
        $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).',';     
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalRecords": '.$iTotal.', ';
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalDisplayRecords": '.$iTotal.', ';
        $sOutput .= '"aaData": [ ';
```